# Avoid code duplication when reading/serializing from DbDataReader?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, lambda, dbdatareader

Consider the `FetchData` method below. It is designed to avoid duplicating the database query code every time you want to fetch some data from the database.

```
List<MyData> myData = new List<MyData();
FetchData((IDataReader reader) =>
   {
       myData.Add(new MyData(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1)));
   }, "usp_get_my_data");
```

It works, but it would be nice if this object creation could somehow live inside the `FetchData` method.

**Is there a better approach?**

Perhaps `FetchData` can be modified to return a list of some type X directly?

```
protected void FetchData(Action<IDataReader> processor, String query)
{
    using (var connection = CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = query;

            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.read())
                {
                    processor(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem would be that FetchData would need to now things about the object that it will be creating to achieve that. Why not make the object creation a part of the actual object (in this case MyData) using an Interface of some sorts  and pass that to FetchData.

Comment: You mean like a factory? And a template to allow for different data types?

Comment: The processor Action that was passed to FetchData, should then live inside MyData onbject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using generics maybe?

```
protected IEnumerable<T> FetchData<T>(Func<IDataReader, T> processor, String query)
{
    using (var connection = CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = query;

            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.read())
                {
                    yield return processor(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the enumeration however you want:

```
var myData = FetchData<MyData>(reader => new MyData(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1)), "usp_get_my_data").ToList();
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Dapper.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which is single file ORM with three different helpers:

1. Execute a query and map the results to a strongly typed List
2. Execute a query and map it to a list of dynamic objects
3. Execute a Command that returns no results

Design patterns used to build this miro-ORM are so helpful. [Dapper.Net is currently being used in StackOverflow](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/04/dapper-released).

Comment: Interesting! Will look into this in future implementations!